# Когда исполняется функция init()?

Tags: golang

Не могу понять как точно работает функция `init()` в `golang`.

Всегда ли она исполняется или только когда есть функция `main()`?
И как происходит исполнение, когда у меня есть несколько подключаемых пакетов?

Comment: А уточнение можно, почему 'FirstAnswer()' будет вызвана раньше 'init()'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `init()` выполняется всегда.

### Пример ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eu0IFnp82mY)):

```
var finalAnswer = FirstAnswer()

func FirstAnswer() int {
    return 1
}

func init() {
    finalAnswer = 0
}

func main() {
    if finalAnswer == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Значение finalAnswer было изменено на 0 в init функции")
    }
}
```

Функция `FirstAnswer()` будет гарантированно выполнена до `init()`, в то время как `init()` будет гарантированно выполнена до `main()`.

Если у тебя несколько пакетов, то функция `init()` будет выполнятся для каждого и только в том порядке, в котором они у вас подключены.

Иногда встречается такое, что у вас нет функции `main()`, но есть `init()`. Это абсолютно нормально, потому что иногда нужно сделать какое-то короткое вычисление, загрузить файл или же инициализировать несколько переменных.

Для большей наглядности работы `init()` для нескольких пакетов, используй картинку ниже: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если есть вопросы задавайте.

Comment: Все очень понятно, спасибо. Можешь порекомендовать какой-нибудь учебник по go, а то я только начинаю и все не очень понятно. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: @Jonny для начала попробуй эту [книгу](http://www.golang-book.com/books/intro)